# How to compare two array with object?

Tags: javascript

I compare id with two array with object.

Here is my function:

```
array1 = [
{ id: 1 },
{ id: 2 },
{ id: 3 }
];

array2 = [
{ id: 1 },
{ id: 2 },
{ id: 3 }
];

const compareFunction = (array1, array2) => {
  array2.map((allValue) => {
    array1.map((value) => {
      allValue.selected = value.id === allValue.id;
    });
  })

 return array2;
}
```

I think I will get the `array2` like

```
[{ id: 1, selected: true }, { id: 2, selected: true },{ id: 3, selected: true }]
```

but actually `array2` become

```
[{ id: 1, selected: false }, { id: 2, selected: false },{ id: 3, selected: true }]
```

Only the last array argument selected become true.

Which step was wrong ? Thanks.

Comment: What's the logic you're looking for? Do you want `selected` to be `true` if the `id` at one index matches the `id` at the same index in the other array, or what?

Comment: Yes, my `array1` sometime will be `[{ id: 1 }]` or `[{  id: 1 }, { id: 2 }]` or `[{  id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }]`

Comment: Sounds like it might be a bit different - are the objects always in order, or are you just trying to see if an object with the same ID *exists*? (eg, if one array is `[{ id: 2 }, { id: 3 }]`, would you want no `selected`s, or two?)

Comment: allValue will be `for-each` loop value -> `{ id: 1 }` `{ id: 2 }` `{ id: 3 }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert the 2nd array to a Set of `id` values. Iterate the 1st array with a `Array.map()` and create a new object for each item, by spreading the current object, and adding the `selected` value. To get the `selected` value check if the Set contains that current item `id`.

```js
const array1 = [{ id: 1 },{ id: 2 },{ id: 3 }];
const array2 = [{ id: 1 },{ id: 2 },{ id: 3 }];

const a2Set = new Set(array2.map(o => o.id))

const result = array1.map(o => ({ ...o, selected: a2Set.has(o.id) }))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

checkout this :

```js
array1 = [{ id: 1 },{ id: 2 },{ id: 3 }];
array2 = [{ id: 1 },{ id: 2 },{ id: 3 }];



const compareFunction = (array1, array2) => {

  const result = [];
  array2.forEach(arr2item => {
      let selected = false;
      for(let arr1item of array1){
          selected = arr1item.id === arr2item.id;
          if(selected)break;
      }
      result.push({id : arr2item.id , selected : selected});
  });

  return result;
}

console.log(compareFunction(array1 , array2));
```